# Make SymbolicLink folder to removable drive which works even when that drive unplugged?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer, symbolic-link, windows-11

When I take photos off my camera onto my laptop to free up space on the camera's SD card, I sometimes need to dump them somewhere until I get round to organising them properly. I have a folder on my laptop for this, but now my laptop is getting full! So I want to move the data in the folder onto an external hard-drive (mapped to V:), but make it appear as though the folder is still on my local C: drive. This is because I have a number of programmes and shortcuts pointing to the local location already.

Often the external drive is unplugged meaning the symbolic link looks broken and can't be used to take images off (e.g. if I'm on holiday without the removable drive, but still want to take photos off the camera, now where do I put them?)

So my question:

Is there a way to have a folder on my C: drive that I can put stuff in when the external drive is unplugged, but when I have the external drive plugged in, all the stuff is automatically moved to the corresponding location on that drive. I'm thinking of an interface like OneDrive - the OneDrive folder works when I'm "unplugged" (no internet connection) and looks to everyone like a regular folder. It even contains placeholder files (ideal but not strictly necessary). And when I'm back online all my stuff goes into the cloud. I guess I could literally just use onedrive but I prefer the physical remote hard drive for file transfer speed.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not with symbolic links (or any other kind of link). Links only remap locations; they have no mechanism to automatically move existing files.

If you want two-way sync with placeholders, you would need a program that's indeed similar to OneDrive but for local sync; I haven't seen anything exactly like that. (At least, not with placeholders – that's probably the most difficult part of creating a sync tool due to the OS integration needed; they are not actually symlinks at all, they're a custom kind of object that relies on a dedicated kernel driver.)

But for one-way sync (i.e. just moving all files from C:\Photos to V:\Photos) it can be done in a much simpler way: just a batch script that moves everything (e.g. using `robocopy` or Unison), and is run whenever you connect the disk. The hard part here is automatically reacting to the disk being connected, although it might be possible to set up a Task Scheduler task... but you could also just double-click the .bat script on your desktop.

Comment: The issue is with that, the folder needs to be a symbolic link or something similar since many programs point to C:/pictures not V:/pictures. However if it is a symlink then I can't drop files in there when it's target is disconnected. I guess drop in C:/folderA then robocopy to V:/pictures and symlink that to C:/pictures. Then all I need to do is change my cameras import folder (from c:/pictures to c:/folderA) but I don't need to modify anything else